# Comboboxes in loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have more than 50 comboboxes on my form that have as items currencies (USD, EUR). Every currency has its own price TextBox.

What I want to do is sum price values based on currencies.
For example, if I have 20 USD I want to get a sum of those 20 price values.
How do I loop through the comboboxes?

Comment: ...add the comboboxes to an array list and then loop through the array list.

Comment: comboboxes or textboxes?  Navigating 50 comboboxes might be slightly icky UI-wise

Comment: @AYETY show a sample data

Comment: Are the combobox and related textbox in one panel? Or otherwise relatable through code? Otherwise it's getting tricky matching them up based only on position on the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;    
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is ComboBox)
    {
        if (c.Text == 'USD')
            i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .Text property of the comboboxes, as @AYETY suggested, but I suppose it depends on how you've populated them and if you'd rather use the value rather than the text, etc.

Anyway, you didn't say where the comboboxes are on the form, so if they are placed in containers, you need to recursively search through the controls on your form, e.g.

```
    public IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControls(Control parentControl)
    {
        List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

        foreach (Control child in parentControl.Controls)
        {
            controls.AddRange(GetChildControls(child));
        }

        controls.Add(parentControl);

        return controls;
    }
```

and then interrogate the comboboxes. Based off using the Text property of the comboboxes, you could do something like this:

```
    private void SumCurrencies()
    {
        var controls = GetChildControls(this);

        foreach (var control in controls.Where(c => c is ComboBox))
        {
            if (control.Text == "USD")
            {
                // do something
            }
            else if (control.Text == "GBP")
            {
                // do something
            }
            else if (control.Text == "EUR")
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```